# Using Powershell To Download Pictures

Tags: powershell, desktop-customization

I'm running Powershell 4.0 and I was wondering, it is possible to automate the task of downloading 5 pictures every day from [a site](http://wall.alphacoders.com/) and store them in my downloads folder? I prefer not to use any third party tool unless I really have to.

I know how to move them from my downloads folder to my pictures folder. It's the downloading part of it that's tricky. The wallpapers are different sizes (each picture was different sizes for HD)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill - I understand that it's not a script writing service. However, I didn't ask for the script. I asked if it was possible to automate the task of downloading 5 pictures every day from a site and store them in my downloads folder? Simple Yes, with an example would have been fine.

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: What did your research tell you? Did you search for "Using Powershell To Download Pictures"? How come you didn't find [Downloading Images from Webpages](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2010/03/17/downloading-images-from-webpages.aspx)? This is the 4th search result!

Comment: If you read http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask (as you were asked to above) you will see it says: "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Answer (score 3):

What you want is the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet:

```
$source = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/Patern_test.jpg"
$destination = "C:\Users\Fazer87\desktop\pattern_test.jpg"
Invoke-WebRequest $source -OutFile $destination
```